# Error en index al no esta logueado

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo un sistema simple de logueo, el problema es que en mi servidor local funciona bien, pero en el servidor `000webhostapp.com` que utilizo de prueba me arroja este error:

`Notice: Undefined index: logueado in /storage/ssd4/990/8179990/public_html/index.php on line 3`

`Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /storage/ssd4/990/8179990/public_html/index.php:3) in /storage/ssd4/990/8179990/public_html/index.php on line 4`

Bien este es el código que utilizo:

index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['logueado'] != "SI"){
header('location: login.php');
exit();
}
$user = $_SESSION['usuario'];

//si ya esta logueado me conecto a la base de datos
include 'conn.php';
```

login.php

```
<?php
session_start();

include 'conn.php';

if(isset($_POST['login'])){
 if(!empty($_POST['pass'])){
   $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE pass=:pass");
   $stmt->execute(array(':pass'=>$_POST['pass']));
   $fila = $stmt->fetch();       
        if($fila > 0){
         $_SESSION['logueado'] = "SI";
         $_SESSION['usuario']  = $fila['nombre'];
         header('location: index.php');
        } else {
            echo '<div class="error"><img class="image" src="icons/exclamation.png"> Contrase&ntilde;a incorrecta. Consulte con el administrador si no la recuerda.</div>';
        }
}
}
```

Entiendo que el primer error me dice que no esta definido `logueado`, no entiendo el segundo, pero en el servidor local no me pasa.

nota: la versión de PHP es la 7.1 en `000webhostapp.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El primer error te lo da porque la variable de `session logueado` no exista.Para solucionarlo podrías añadir `if(isset($_SESSION['logueado']))` antes de comprobra su valor.

El segundo error es porque no tienes bien tabulado el código `PHP` y la etiqueta header suele dar estos problemas. Para solucionarlo tabulalo bien.

```
<?php
   session_start();
   if($_SESSION['logueado'] != "SI"){
      header('location: login.php');
      exit();
   }
   $user = $_SESSION['usuario'];

   //si ya esta logueado me conecto a la base de datos
   include 'conn.php';
```

Comment: Lo arregle y me funciono bien... nunca pensé que tenia que usar `isset`. Algo tan simple y yo rompiéndome la cabeza. Muchas gracias.